# how to change the color of menu text wordpress?

Tags: menus

http://fun88us.com/category/gioi-thie%CC%A3u-nha-cai-fun88/. Hi everyone , I am trying to change the color of menu text but it does not work. I dont understand CCS and PHP

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```
.main-navigation a:link {
    color:red;
}
```

I took the color red as example.
You can also use Hexcolors. Just replace red with the desired color or hexcolor.